# Why does List view in Nativescript with Typescript bring error self.parent.parent not an object?

Tags: listview, angular, nativescript

> Update: The issue was a lack of understanding the  syntax. 
>   And the following question was written with general syntax resulting
>   in an example that doesn't create an error. See answer for
>   explanation.

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525449/correct-way-to-populate-listview-with-object-items), But I follow the answer that is given and have a new issue.

> caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'self.parent.parent.context.item.name')

why is it referencing self.parent.parent? and not parent.child? is this where my issue lies?

app.component.html

```
<TabView #tabview [selectedIndex]="tabindex" class="">

        <DockLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab1'}">
            <StackLayout dock='left'>
                <ListView [items]="items">
                    <template let-item="item">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label [text]='item.name' textWrap="true"> </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                    </template>
                </ListView>
             </StackLayout>
        </DockLayout>


    </TabView>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page"
import { ListView } from "ui/list-view"
import { Item } from "../item";
import { ItemService } from "../../services/item.service";
import dockModule = require("ui/layouts/dock-layout");




@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  providers: [ItemService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 

  public items: Item[];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { 

  };



  getItems(): void {
    this.itemService.getItems().then(items => this.items = items);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();
  }


}
```

item.ts

```
export class Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

item.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Item } from '../item';
import { ITEMS } from '../database/mock-items';

@Injectable()

export class ItemService {
    getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(ITEMS);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code gives me a list view that populates [object Object] for each instance.  But at least it populates something. `<ListView [items]="accounts ">
                    <ListView.itemTemplate *ngFor="let account of accounts">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label [text]='account' textWrap="true"> </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                    </ListView.itemTemplate>
               </ListView>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that runs into this or a similar problem.

In the end, maybe it is intuitive for everyone else, but I thought it was mere coincidence that everyone was using `<template let-item="item">` as their code. Truthfully, the code above will work because the template tag is written correctly. But the problem I faced was I attempted to write the syntax with another keyword. `<template let-item="account">`.  In comparison to using `*ngFor "let account of accounts"` This will give the

> not an object

error like I mentioned above. When making the question I edited unknowingly to reflect a correct syntax.